# socket.io not working on shared hosting after installing node.js

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, socket.io, shared-hosting

I have installed node.js on my shared godaddy hosting by running this php script

https://github.com/niutech/node.php/blob//nodmastere.php

After running start it says node app started and gives pid.
When client emits an event it is listened at server and send
back to the same client where as in my node server code it 
emits to all clients.
server code for like process:

```
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
    console.log( "New client !" );
client.on( 'likes', function( data ) {
        console.log( 'like done ' + data.id);


        io.sockets.emit( 'likes', { id: data.id } );
    });
}
```

It gives the following error.

http://undefined/socket.io/1/?t=1465921249260 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Is the error coming from the client (that's what it looks like)?  If so, then please include the relevant client code.

Comment: socket.io uses the Websocket protocol, AJAX and a number of alternatives (including flash sockets)... but the tag `sockets` refers to low level socket programing. Please update your tag from `sockets` to `websocket`.

Comment: ok sure will update.

Comment: on client side i have:   var socket = io.connect(); and  socket.on( 'likes', function( data ) {} code it is working fine on local host . Problem is on establishing connection with server.